# Bootstrap 2.3.2 forms, aligning width of inline form controls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to build a form which has structure like given in the screen below

[image]

Amount control group has three input elements but the right edge of last element has to be aligned with Frequency object's input..

I can't make it in bootstrap somehow, can anyone please help me out?

Code here :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="mDrugAmount">Amount </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input class="input-small" data-bind="value: Dose" type="text">
         <select class="input-mini">
            <option value="">  </option>
            <option value="">mg</option>
            <option value="">mL</option>
         </select>
         <select class="input-mini">
            <option value="">  </option>
            <option value="">IM</option>
            <option value="">IV</option>
            <option value="">subcut</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="mDrugFrequency">Frequency </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <select>
            <option value="">  </option>
            <option value="">4 hourly</option>
            <option value="">6 hourly</option>
            <option value="">8 hourly</option>
            <option value="">alto die</option>
            <option value="">bd</option>
            <option value="">bd</option>
            <option value="">daily</option>
            <option value="">infusion</option>
            <option value="">mane</option>
            <option value="">nocte</option>
            <option value="">qid</option>
            <option value="">tds</option>
            <option value="">weekly</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="mCommenceDate">Commence </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" >
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="mPrescriptionDate">Until </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group submit-row">
      <div class="control-label">
         <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="    click: $parent.changePrescription">Submit</a>
      </div>
      <div class="control-label">
         <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: $parent.ceasePrescription">Cease</a>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is my JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/az6zpha3/1/

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/az6zpha3/2/

Answer (score -1):

i have updated the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/az6zpha3/6/

you can change the class Name if it is conflicting with bootstrap

```
.form-horizontal{
    width:400px;
}

.input-mini{
   min-width:30%;
}
```

HTML

i have changed class name "input-small" to "input-mini"

```
<form class="form-horizontal" _lpchecked="1">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="mDrugAmount">Amount </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-mini" data-bind="value: Dose" type="text">
            <select class="input-mini"><option value="">  </option><option value="">mg</option><option value="">mL</option></select>
            <select class="input-mini"><option value="">  </option><option value="">IM</option><option value="">IV</option><option value="">subcut</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="mDrugFrequency">Frequency </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select><option value="">  </option><option value="">4 hourly</option><option value="">6 hourly</option><option value="">8 hourly</option><option value="">alto die</option><option value="">bd</option><option value="">bd</option><option value="">daily</option><option value="">infusion</option><option value="">mane</option><option value="">nocte</option><option value="">qid</option><option value="">tds</option><option value="">weekly</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="mCommenceDate">Commence </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="mPrescriptionDate">Until </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group submit-row">
        <div class="control-label">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="    click: $parent.changePrescription">Submit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="control-label">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: $parent.ceasePrescription">Cease</a>
        </div>

        <div class="control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share your css in fiddle

Comment: I have no css applied to it apart from the bootstrap one.